# WatsonIOT platform: Event are display but does not appear when adding new card in tab

Tags: watson-iot

I connected a Raspberry Pi to Watson IoT platform and I can receive the event in the event section "Recent Event"

The format is JSON and I have an event with a value of `{"d":{"temp":"40"}}` for instance.

However when I want to display it in the tab section, I add a graph, connect a new data:

```
Event : +
Property: temp measure
Name: temp 
type : text
units: °C
```

Then nothing happens. If I use the quickstart from nod-red it displays properly.

Does someone have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title and the contents of your question to try to improve readability and grammar. Please read the help section on how to ask and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Good luck!

Comment: Try Event: d, Property: temp